# login api not hitting server in first attempt its going into failure block

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

whenever a login button is clicked in first attempt it always goes into failure block (internet connectivity is not the issue) and in 2nd attempt it works absolutely fine....can anybody tell whats actual problem really is ?

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[manager POST:urlll parameters:json progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask* task, id responseObject) {
    int tip=0;
    int bit=0;

    NSDictionary * myUserDictionary = responseObject;
    BOOL auth=[[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"isAuth"]boolValue];     [GeneralHelper HideActivityIndicator:self.currentActivityloginView];
    if(auth == YES)
    {
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setObject:[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"FullName"] forKey:@"FullName"];
        [prefs setObject:[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"EmpID"] forKey:@"EmpID"];

        [prefs setObject:[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"EmailID"] forKey:@"EmailID"];

        [prefs setObject:[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"FirstName"] forKey:@"FirstName"];
        [prefs setObject:[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"LastName"] forKey:@"LastName"];
        [prefs setObject:[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"UserStatus"] forKey:@"UserStatus"];
        [prefs setObject:[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"UserID"] forKey:@"UserID"] ;
        [prefs setObject:[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"ManualRead"] forKey:@"ManualRead"] ;

        [self CanUserRescheduleCheck];


        //Clear notifications
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

        /*REMOVE THE FOLLOWING LINE TO ENABLE PROMPT FOR MANUAL*/
        [prefs setObject:@"1" forKey:@"ManualRead"];
        /////////////

        bit = [[prefs objectForKey:@"ManualRead"]intValue];
        tip = [[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"ManualRead"] intValue];
        if (bit==0)
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"warning" message:@"Have You Read The Manual?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"YES" otherButtonTitles:@"NO", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        if (bit==1)

        {


            _MasterVC= [[MasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];

            [_loginView removeFromSuperview];
            //   self.refappdele.window.rootViewController=_MasterVC;

            //[TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"LoginSuccess"];
            [RefHelper SetMasterRef:_MasterVC];
            [RefHelper GetAppRef].window.rootViewController=_MasterVC;

        }

        AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        [delegate startLocationService];

        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self registerDeviceToken];
        });


    }
    else
    {
        [DialogAlerter ErrorAlerter:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Login failed with following error: %@",[myUserDictionary objectForKey:@"AuthMessage"]]];
        NSLog(@"************* ERROR OCCURED HERE *******************");
        NSLog(@"isAuth: %i", auth);
    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Response: %@",error);

    [GeneralHelper HideActivityIndicator:self.currentActivityloginView];

    [DialogAlerter ErrorAlerter:@"A Request Error Occured: Please Try Again or Check your network connectivity"];

    //[TestFlight passCheckpoint:[error localizedDescription]];
}];
```

Comment: what is the error response message ?

Comment: response message  contains a message in string format from Web api

Comment: I suggest to check all data and meta data in the response (status code, header, content, etc.). Moreover, if the content type of the first response is string whereas you wait for Json, a problem occurred for wrong content type in response.

Comment: i think thats not the problem if it could be for instance it would never go in success and thats not the case in 2nd attempt it works fine...